# vb.net WebClient.DownloadString fails with exception

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017, webclient

I am working on a program in VS 2017 coding in VB.Net.  The program downloads Web pages using Net.WebClient.DownloadString and then parses the data.  It worked fine for a year or more then one day I started getting an exception when downloading the pages.

The ex.Message is: 'The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.'

The ex.InnerException.Message is: 'Unable to write data to the transport connection: A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied.'

I have VS 2017 installed on 2 other PC's at this location and on 1 at another location.  They all continue to run the code without exception.  It is only an issue on this PC.

The code is below (I changed the Web address but it fails for any valid URL).

Any ideas why this fails on my main PC only?

```
Public Function DownloadData() As Boolean

    Dim strURL As String = "https://www.google.com/"
    Dim strOutput As String

    Try
        Using WC As New Net.WebClient

            strOutput = WC.DownloadString(strURL)

            If strOutput.Length > 0 Then
                If ParseData(strOutput) = True Then
                    Return True
                End If
            Else
                Return False
            End If
        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.InnerException.Message, "Error")

    End Try

End Function
```

Comment: Because you now have a firewall that blocks you?

Comment: If you have code that works and then suddenly doesn't, the first place you should be looking is not at the code but at what has changed, software- or hardware-wise, at the time the code stopped working.

Comment: No hardware changes have been made.  No software changes that would affect downloading a Webpage.  NOTE: This also fails when using the Web browser control but I have no issues using a Web browser on the PC.

Comment: All 3 PC's at this location are on the same network and the other 2 PC's run the code without issue.

Comment: Windows Firewall disabled on all 3 PC's.

Comment: I found a post that suggested adding:  WC.Headers(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent) = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)"

Comment: It worked for a little while then stopped working again.  Now getting:  "The remote name could not be resolved: 'https://www.google.com'".